# P Value interpretation in K fold Validation

Tags: logistic, cross-validation, references, p-value

I am validating a credit risk model. I did a k fold validation to check the stability of the estimates. The estimates of the model are quite stable but the variables now have a high P value(above 0.1) in the 5 folds that were created. The variables had a very low P-value during development. Can i question the model developer about the variable significance? Is there a paper I could read something related to this.Any suggestions would be helpful.Are there any statistical tests that should be done before bringing this up with the team.

Comment: I'm guessing an issue here is that actual credit events are quite rare in the data? Dealing with households? small firms? large firms?

Comment: Dealing with an Application scorecard for a bank. Is there a threshold to the sample size and the number of bads in each of the sample?

Comment: And i do have more than 100 bads in each of the samples.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have inadequately small sample size, so that you lose statistical power when 1/5 samples are drawn from the dataset.

Comment: Dealing with an Application scorecard for a bank. Is there a threshold to the sample size and the number of bads/events in each of the sample?

Comment: Well, assuming you have chosen the appropriate regression method for your data, and all the assumptions of the model are satisfied, accuracy of cross-validation is assesed through calculation of Pearson's correlation coefficient. So, indirectly, you can estimate adequate sample size of validation set by the expected r and wanted P values. You can use this calculator [link](http://www.sample-size.net/correlation-sample-size/)[link] to calculate how many samples you should have for assesment of P values for r in validation set.